# getting tomcat to log webapp name in logging statements

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

Using tomcat's JULI logging (extension of jdk logging), is it possible to get log statements to include the context path of the webapp (for example /myapp).  I have the same webapp deployed a few times with different configuration parameters in the web.xml.  It would be very helpful to understand which webapp was spitting out which log statements.

Currently, the log output looks like:

```
Feb 22, 2012 9:37:57 AM org.mypackage.MyClass init
INFO: Model has been initialized
Feb 22, 2012 9:37:57 AM org.mypackage.MyClass init
INFO: after loading model: 1329921477445
```

I'd like to be able to include the context path of the webapp (or webapp name) before the class name.  Something along these lines:

```
Feb 22, 2012 9:37:57 AM /mywebapp org.mypackage.MyClass init
INFO: Model has been initialized
Feb 22, 2012 9:37:57 AM /mywebapp org.mypackage.MyClass init
INFO: after loading model: 1329921477445
```

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Use SLF4J and Logback in your webapps. Do not rely on Java Logging (JULI).